Generate all years between two timestamps
As part of a larger Postgres query, I generate all years between two given timestamps (timestamptz):
select to_char(generate_series, 'YYYY') from generate_series(
'2022-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz, 
'2023-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz,
'1 year' );

Which returns:
'2022'
'2023'

The issue is, if there is less than one year between both timestamps, only the first year is returned. I need a set of all involved years, regardless of the the interval between both timestamps, e.g.:
select to_char(generate_series, 'YYYY') from generate_series(
'2022-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz, 
'2023-06-13 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz,
'1 year' );

Only returns:
'2022'

But I would like it to return:
'2022'
'2023'

Is there some way to achieve this?

Just extract() the year from the timestamp and then use that to generate the series? Maybe wrap in a case statement for when the first timestamp is greater than the second.

The year of a timestamptz (timestamp with time zone]) value is not strictly determined. It's still the year 2024 in New York, when I wish "Happy New Year 2025" in Vienna.
Only date or timestamp (timestamp without time zone) are deterministic in this regard.
To avoid corner case issues you must define the time zone for your query in one way or another.
Here is one way:
SELECT generate_series(EXTRACT('year' FROM '2022-06-14 11:00+0'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna')::int
                     , EXTRACT('year' FROM '2023-06-13 11:00+0'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna')::int) AS the_year;

Here is another:
SELECT EXTRACT('year' FROM ts)::int AS the_year
FROM   generate_series(date_trunc('year', '2022-06-14 11:00+0'::timestamptz, 'Europe/Vienna')
                     , date_trunc('year', '2023-06-13 11:00+0'::timestamptz, 'Europe/Vienna')
                     , interval '1 year') ts;

date_trunc() allows a 3rd parameter to pass the time zone since Postgres 12 - which only makes sense for timestamptz, obviously.
Replace with your time zone, or use timestamp values to begin with.
Assuming the second timestamp is guaranteed to be after the first, or you have to do more / define how to deal with it.
Basics:

Ignoring time zones for Postgres timestamps
Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL


I'm not sure exactly why you're doing it this way, but what you can do is the following - if your second date is less than 1 year from your first, then you can use the following (hacky!) code - if you're taking the dates from somewhere else.
(all of the code below is available on the fiddle here):
This makes use of the PostgreSQL AGE() function:

age ( timestamp, timestamp ) → interval
Subtract arguments, producing a “symbolic” result that uses years and
months, rather than just days
age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13') → 43 years 9 mons
27 days
age ( timestamp ) → interval
Subtract argument from current_date (at midnight)
age(timestamp '1957-06-13') → 62 years 6 mons 10 days

SELECT 
  EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM gen_year.n) AS the_year  -- as specific as possible!
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES
  (
    '2022-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz, 
  
    CASE
      WHEN
        AGE
        (
          '2023-06-13 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'Europe/Dublin', 
          '2022-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'Europe/Dublin'
        )
        < '1 YEAR'::INTERVAL 
        THEN '2022-06-14 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'Europe/Dublin'
           + '1 YEAR'::INTERVAL
      ELSE
        '2023-06-13 11:00:00.000+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'Europe/Dublin'
    END,
  '1 YEAR'::INTERVAL
) AS gen_year(n)

--
-- returns INTEGER values rather than strings for a number - **_always_** better!
--

Result:
the_year
2022
2023

